# React smooth scroll only partially working

Tags: reactjs, scroll, smoothing

I am trying to implement a smooth scroll in React, with no jquery. I have downloaded and installed react-scrollable-anchor from npm. The smooth scroll works with the first two items in my menu, and not with the last 2. See [my website nav](http://emilypancake.com).

```
<div className="App">
    <div>
        <div className="header">
            <div className="logobox">
                <img className="logo" src="/eplogo.png" alt="logo"/>
            </div>
            <nav className="nav">
              <a className="navitem" href="#projects">
                <p>Projects</p>
              </a>
              <a className="navitem" href="#about">
                <p>About</p>
              </a>
              <a className="navitem" href="#resume">
                <p>Resume</p>
              </a>
              <a className="navitem" href="#contact">
                <p>Contact</p>
              </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <header className="heading">
            <a className="name" href="/">
                <h1 className="App-title">Emily Pancake</h1>
            </a>
            <h2 className="tagline" >Web Developer and Design Enthusiast</h2>
            <div className={this.state.ghost}>
              <p className={this.state.typewriter}>{this.state.jokeText}</p>
            </div>
            <a className="arrowDown" href="#projects" rel="noopener noreferrer"><Button shape="circle" icon="down" /></a>
            <ScrollableAnchor id={'projects'}>
            <h2 className="sectionTitle notop">Projects</h2>
          </ScrollableAnchor>
        </header>
        <section className="projectList">
            <Projects projects={projects} key="2" />
        </section>
        <ScrollableAnchor id={"about"} name="about"><About key="1"/></ScrollableAnchor>
        <ScrollableAnchor id={"resume"} name="resume"><Resume key="2"/></ScrollableAnchor>
        <ScrollableAnchor id={"contact"} name="contact"><Footer key="1"/></ScrollableAnchor>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get it to work on "resume" and "contact." The only difference is that they are functional react components instead of classes. The error seems to be related: "Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail."

Comment: So how did you solve your problem ?